# Post Image to WCF Service From Fiddler

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services, fiddler

I have been working on WCF Services. I have a service that accepts a few parameters including Image. Here is my Request XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<GPProcess xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <Action>
      <Device />
      <GenopalAuthorization />
      <P1x>0</P1x>
      <P1y>0</P1y>
      <P2x>0</P2x>
      <P2y>0</P2y>
      <PalletName />
      <Picture i:nil="true" />
      <PictureShare>false</PictureShare>
      <PictureURL />
   </Action>
</GPProcess>
```

The problem is that, I want to test this Web Service on Fiddler. I need help that how can I post an Image to Web Service through Fiddler? and what should be the content-type?

With Best wishes

Comment: I think Fiddler is used to trace/debug the calls to a service rather directly test a service. If you would like to read through the description in this link for Fiddler website: http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/

Answer (score 0):

It might be better to create a proxy class to call your service and build a simple client that uses that proxy. You can then monitor the traffic between the client and the service using Fiddler...